# React app with mongodb(cloud) backend Deployment issue on vercel

Tags: node.js, routes, deployment, serverless, vercel

I created an app frontend in react and create and mongodb(cloud) through mongoose and integrate it with frontend. My app runs on localhost:5000, which shows the frontend with backend but when I post it on vercel it shows me 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.